# Storing dynamic image files in a web app in the api server file system. (nodejs / express)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, azure, express, amazon-s3

In my web app The users are given option to upload and retrieve images. The only problem is where exactly to store them during production?

For development purposes the files are being stored in a '/public/images' directory and the path to those file are stored in the database.I have made the express app use this directory as a static folder so that this path can be used to access a image from the front end.

The problem in production with this is from what I have read is that if I deploy the api server to a cloud app service like Azure or Amazon EC2 , the dynamic files will be wiped  out during occassional system reboot or system checks or redeployment of code and this data will be lost.

But file system is cheaper form of storage without the cost for the cloud.

Now my question is that is there an option for me to store the dynamic images in the api server filesystem like I am doing with my express app, during deployment in a cheap manner? Also the file storage should be permanent.

Or I will have to go for a cloud provider like S3 or Google cloud storage in production since that is the industry standard for this kind of usecase?

Are there any other drawbacks to this file system approach I am not seeing if yes pls do mention that also.

I have tried deploying on heroku but heroku has a ephemeral file storage from the get go where the FS gets cleaned every 24 hours.

I have never really tried Amazon EC2 or Azure deployment but I have only read blogs here and there.

Comment: You must use one of the cloud storage service like AWS S3 or Azure Blob storage, period.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran Yeah I figured there is no workaround for that. Do you think the Google Cloud Platform might be also good to consider since they offer 300USD free credits to start? And this project is in a very early stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding AWS, the standard service to serve static web content is S3: there is an [official documented example of implementation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/serve-static-content-in-an-amazon-s3-bucket-through-a-vpc-by-using-amazon-cloudfront.html) that is very clear.
S3 is in the free tier with 5GB of storage for the first year.
 
Even after the free tier is very, very cheap: [Amazon S3 pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/?nc1=h_ls).